# Is in Google Colab a prebuild download of ImageNet for academic research?

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, imagenet

I've been trying to work with ImageNet in Colab using Pytorch. I know that there was a Pytorch class (`torchvision.datasets.ImageNet`) that had that functionality, but is no longer providing the Dataset with the flag `download`.

Is there another way to work with that Dataset in Google Colab?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: show minimal working code which makes problem. As I remeber few weeks ago there was question about `ImageNet` in `sklearn` and problem was server with `ImageNet` - it was hanging and it couldn't send dataset.

Comment: base on information on https://www.image-net.org you have to manually download it. And then you will have to upload it to Google Colab. And some subset is on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/imagenet-object-localization-challenge/overview/description) which need to register and login.